# Using np.where to increase Year & Week in prediction column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am working to create a target column that includes the following week's number and year. I have the beginning of this complete, but I am struggling to account for week 52 and the need to reset the week to 1 and add +1 to the year.

Here is the coding for the YEAR_WEEK-targ column that is running successfully.

```
df_calls_subweek_target['YEAR_WEEK_targ'] = df_calls_subweek_target['YEAR'].astype(str) + "_" + (df_calls_subweek_target['WEEK']+1).astype(str)
```

| YEAR_WEEK | YEAR_WEEK_targ |
| --- | --- |
| 2008_38 | 2008_39 |
| 2008_39 | 2008_40 |

I am trying to figure out how to code for the first week of the year. Using np.where makes sense to me, but as you can see, I am not an expert.

```
df_calls_subweek_target['YEAR_WEEK_targ'] = np.where(df_calls_subweek_target['YEAR_WEEK_targ'] == 52,   (df_calls_subweek_target['YEAR']+1).astype(str) + "_" + (df_calls_subweek_target['WEEK'] ==1).astype(str))
```

So, need to figure out how to say when week = 52, increase year + 1 and week = 1.

Looking for any recommendations on how to approach this case!

Answer (score 0):

A *tricky* solution would be to [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) the values where `week=52` and replace them by `0`.

```
s = df["WEEK"].mask(df["WEEK"].eq(52)).fillna(0, downcast="infer").add(1)
​
df["YEAR_WEEK_targ"] = df['YEAR'].astype(str) + "_" + s.astype(str).str.zfill(2)
```

An alternative, you can also use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df["YEAR_WEEK_targ"] = np.where(df["WEEK"].eq(52),
                                df['YEAR'].astype(str) + "_01",
                                df['YEAR'].astype(str) + "_" + df["WEEK"].astype(str))
```

NB : For the sake of clarity, I used (`df`) instead of (`df_calls_subweek_target`)

​Output :

```
print(df)

   YEAR  WEEK YEAR_WEEK_targ
0  2008    38        2008_39
1  2008    39        2008_40
2  2008    52        2008_01
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def function1(ss:pd.Series):
    ss=ss.astype(int)
    if ss.col1==52:
        ss.col1=1
        ss.col0=ss.col0+1
    return "{}_{}".format(ss.col0,ss.col1)

df1['YEAR_WEEK_targ'] = df1.YEAR_WEEK.str.split("_",expand=True).add_prefix("col").apply(function1,axis=1)
df1
```

out

```
 YEAR_WEEK YEAR_WEEK_targ
0   2008_38        2008_38
1   2008_39        2008_39
2   2008_52         2009_1
```